# c# MVC multiple routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have two route mapping,

```
RouteConfig.MapRoute(routes, WebRouteName.FullForVanityUrl, "_/{community}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { tenant = defaultTenant, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { tenant = @"[^-]+" });
RouteConfig.MapRoute(routes, WebRouteName.Full, "{tenant}-{community}/{controller}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { tenant = defaultTenant, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { tenant = @"[^-]+" });
```

I have 2 separate URL,`http://localhost/demo/` and `http://demo.localhost/`

How to detect `WebRouteName.Full` for `http://localhost/demo/` and how to detect `WebRouteName.FullForVanityUrl` for `http://demo.localhost/`?

right now `http://localhost/demo/` is redirecting to `http://localhost/_/default/Home/HomePage`, which is wrong. It should be `http://localhost/demo-default/Home/HomePage`

and `http://demo.localhost/` is redirecting to `http://demo.localhost/_/default/Home/HomePage`, which is right

Comment: that sounds like a UrlRewrite job as opposed to a MapRoute one, but I could be wrong

Comment: As your question is worded, it is unclear what you are asking. Routing maps an incoming URL to a controller action method (and back again), not to another URL. Redirecting or rewriting can be used to redirect or map a request URL to another URL, but it is unclear which of these is right for your scenario. Note that routing and rewriting happen server-side, but redirecting happens client-side (meaning you will see the URL change in the browser). You state that in one case your "redirect" is working, but you haven't posted any code that can do a redirect, so please post it.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Can we have MapRoute depend on URL